# what is a word for when someone compliments another insincerely?

Tags: meaning

Like in an attempt to win you over for some reason or another, in that sense?.. What I mean here is not that one is wheedling, coaxing or sweet-talking, but rather complimenting hypocritically.
I know it sounds somewhat confusing but I believe there is a slight threadlike difference, at least, there is certainly in my language.

Much obliged for your remarks, beforehand.

Comment: What do you say in your language?

Comment: @ermanen Well we say quite a few actually, but the issue is I speak accentual/dialectal Arabic. That is a colloquial form of Arabic. There is of course the standard classic Arabic which is the original Language but there are 24 dialects due to 24 Arab countries, and I happen to not speak the standard I'm afraid. So I can give you the words we say but they will be to no avail because they are not standard. I'm terribly sorry in that regard I cannot help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I believe the word you're looking for is *flattery*

Answer (score 2):

*Blandishments* are compliments that are showered so to gain favours.

Answer (score 1):

In American English slang, this is commonly known as a *left-handed compliment*.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could go about saying this.

- You could call it a *back-handed compliment*, a compliment that contains some underlying insult.
- You could say that the person giving the compliment was being *snide* or, more colloquially, *two-faced*.
- You could say that the compliment was *feigned*.

Hope one of these suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

"Patronizing" can be seen as a suitable answer given the appropriate context:

[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/patronizing) says

> If someone is *patronizing*, they speak or behave toward you in a way that seems friendly, but shows that they think they are superior to you in some way.

In other words, they are speaking to you positively (or complimentary) under a veil of insincerity.

Comment: Hi, Dan. Your suggestion may be good, depending on what meaning of _patronizing_ you have in mind. But for the benefit of site visitors who may not know the precise meaning you allude to (and who may have opened this page in hopes of getting a complete, usable answer), please consider adding to your answer a suitable definition of _patronizing_ from a reputable dictionary. By way of encouragement, if you make that extra effort, I will gladly upvote your answer, thus canceling out the downvote you've received (presumably from someonewho thought your answer was too bare-bones to be of much use).

Answer (score 0):

False compliment, false flattery, feigned flattery

Answer (score 0):

Adulation.  I believe that might be a very good fit for the word you were searching for earlier.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please edit your answer to specify why you think it fits the question.